# Generified static method invocation not compiling in Java 8

Tags: generics, compiler-errors, java-8, compiler-bug

Long story short, following code is not compiling in **Java 8** but was compiling and executing well in **Java 7**:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Class instance = null;
    meth(instance); // compiler error here
}

private static <K, T extends Enum<T> & IAliased<K>> void meth(final Class<T> clazz) {

}
```

The **error occurs** at mentioned line with message: `The method meth(Class<T>) in the type AnotherSpike is not applicable for the arguments (Class)`.

While **I** totally **understand** that such code is **not 100% typesafe**, I need very similar invocation working in production code in **Java 8** (and it was compiling with warnings and working well in **Java 7**).

The interesting thing is that above code compiles fine (*with warnings, but this is ok*) in following cases:

1. if `& IAliased<K>` is removed from method signature:

   ```
   private static <K, T extends Enum<T>> void meth(final Class<T> clazz)
   ```
2. if `& IAliased<K>` is replaced with `& IAliased` in signature:

   ```
   private static <K, T extends Enum<T> & IAliased> void meth(final Class<T> clazz)
   ```

Two above observations has lead me to the thought that **this is** more like a **compiler bug in Java 8** rather than thoughtful enhancement to the Java 8 compiler, though I may be mistaken.

Anyway, can somebody advise on **how can I pass raw instance** of `Class` **to** `meth` **method with such signature** without compiler errors?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hmmm ... While compiling with `javac` I still get only the warnings, Eclipse gives me the error you describe. This is most likely a bug in the IDE's internal compiler.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose you're absolutely right - just tried with `javac` and it compiled with warnings. My bad that I didn't tried it in `javac` first. I will create bug for JDT and post a link to it here. BTW, please put your comment as an answer if you want it to be upvoted and accepted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the IDE's internal compiler.

With Eclipse I get the same error you are describing. However, when using the JDK compiler I still get only the warnings and it compiles.